# Can the gstreamer play the media content which sended using this client code below?

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, gstreamer

I want to write client server application to stream media content from pc (linux) to android. Client side code i have decided to write using posix sockets. On sever side (on android device) i think to use gstreamer api. Client code is shown below in listing
I interested in this question, can the gstreamer play the media content which sended using this client code ?

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "\nError: Missing parameter" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Usage:\n\tmain <file path>\n" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    char* file_name = new char[len];
    file_name = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Cannot open the file by given path" << std::endl;
        fclose (file);
    }
    char buf[portion];
    bzero((void*)buf, portion);
    int quantum = 0;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(2000);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");        
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    bzero((void*)buf, portion);        
    int bytes_read = 0;
    while( (bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, 8192, file) ) > 0) {
        int s = send(sockfd, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        bzero((void*)buf, portion);
        if (s == -1) {
            std::cout << "Error: The data connot be sended" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << " . ";
    }
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among many other things you can use tcpserversrc with host=127.0.0.1 and port=2000. This will create a source element that will listen for a TCP connection on port 2000 of 127.0.0.1 and then pass the data to a gstreamer pipeline.